# Regex for Validetta jQuery plugin

Tags: jquery, regex

I am validating an input field with the Validetta jQuery plugin ([regex demo](http://lab.hasanaydogdu.com/validetta/demo/basics.html)).

I want to allow numbers, letter, spaces and dashes.

I'm trying to create the correct regex for the Validetta parameters:

```
validators: {
regExp: {
regname : {
pattern : [pattern here]
errorMessage : 'Only numbers, letters, spaces and dashes allowed'
}
}
}
```

Here is a link to a regex tester with prefilled regex and results:

http://regexr.com/3e10d

It seems to be matching everything I want it to match.

It provides the regex in three formats:

Expression:  `/([A-Z0-9 -])/ig`

Pattern:  `([A-Z0-9 -])`

Javascript:  `text.match(/([A-Z0-9 -])/ig);`

These are not having the desired effect when used in Validetta, eg:

```
pattern : /([A-Z0-9 -])/ig,
```

This validates:  `web's test`
This doesn't:  `'web`

**OR:**

```
pattern : ([A-Z0-9 -]),
```

Causes page not to load with Firebug error:

> // SyntaxError: expected expression, got ']'

What pattern should I be using in Validetta to get the desired results?

Comment: You need to add anchors: `^[-A-Za-z0-9 ]+$`. Additionally, it is always wise to put the dash at the beginning as it has different meanings in a character class.

Comment: Specifically `/^[-A-Za-z0-9 ]+$/`, add as answer if you like?

Comment: Done that - did it work ? :)

Comment: Yep, had to wait 7 minutes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As said in the comments, you probably want:

```
^[-A-Za-z0-9 ]+$
```

Note the dash in the beginning as well as the anchors which will only allow the specified characters in the class **from the beginning to the end**.